# Getting Eurostat/Gisco postcodes for UK

Tags: r

Is there any chance to extract Gisco-postal-codes for UK? Is it impossible since Brexit or am I doing something wrong?

```
library(giscoR)

gisco_get_postalcodes(country = "GBR") # using "UK" does not make it better. For other
# countries - EU members and non-EU members - the query works

#> gisco_get_postalcodes(country = "GBR")
#Simple feature collection with 0 features and 15 fields
#Bounding box:  xmin: NA ymin: NA xmax: NA ymax: NA
#Geodetic CRS:  ETRS89
#[1] OBJECTID       POSTCODE       CNTR_ID        PC_CNTR        NUTS3_2021     CODE           GISCO_ID       NSI_CODE       LAU_NAT       
#[10] LAU_LATIN      COASTAL        CITY_ID        GREATER_CI     FUA_ID         DGURBA         _ogr_geometry_
#<0 Zeilen> (oder row.names mit Länge 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [source code](https://github.com/rOpenGov/giscoR/blob/main/R/gisco_get_postalcodes.R) of `giscoR::gisco_get_postalcodes()`, there are the following lines:

```r
gisco_get_postalcodes <- function(year = "2020",
                                  country = NULL,
                                  cache_dir = NULL,
                                  update_cache = FALSE,
                                  verbose = FALSE) {
  year <- as.character(year)
  if (!(year %in% c("2020"))) {
    stop("Year should be 2020")
  }
  cache_dir <- gsc_helper_detect_cache_dir()

  if (year == "2020") {
    url <- "https://gisco-services.ec.europa.eu/tercet/Various/PC_2020_PT_SH.zip"
  }
```

The data provided in this zip file doesn't contain the UK data, which is why this function returns an empty dataframe.

However, it seems that you can download the UK postal codes by yourself [here](https://gisco-services.ec.europa.eu/tercet/flat-files) (select "UK" and "2021").

Comment: Yes, but it's not excactly the same content. Especially the longitude and latitude are missing.

Comment: You could open an issue on the github of the package to ask them directly if postal codes for UK can be accessed with `giscoR`